# Drupal 7 updating content via a service ( external source )

Tags: web-services, drupal-7

I need to create a service that will receive an XML feed at any given time that will have data related to a content-type.

Could someone please advise me what modules i should use to develop a solution.

So

Another server will post a xml feed with instruction add/delete/update content in the xml

I will require to update the content type from the XML feed post

I have previously used the migrate module but this is run on my side through cron or manual. The main difference here is that i could receive the post from the other server at any given time or possibly multiple concurrent posts.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for the Services 3 module. You can make a resources module to that which parses your xml file an does the work for you. The services module is handling rest/rpc connections for you.